# Error C2665 'std::vector<cv::String,std::allocator<cv::String>>::push_back': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am a beginner c++ and I have been trying to take in images from a folder as an input. Any help is welcome. I am using VScode, and the issue that push_back gives me an error stating that:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Detail Description
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=cv::String, _Alloc=std::allocator<cv::String>]" matches the argument list HelloWorld  D:\VS Projects\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.cpp 103     argument types are: (WCHAR [260])
            object type is: std::vector<cv::String, std::allocator<cv::String>>
```

Added the code below and hoping to find a solution to the issue.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include<string.h>
using namespace cv;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using namespace std;
char search[200];

    vector<string> getNamesOfFile(string folderPath)
    {
        // vector of names of file within a folder 
        std::vector<string> names_ofFiles;

        wchar_t search[200];
        // convert your string search path into char array
        wprintf(search, "%s*.*", folderPath.c_str());

        //  WIN32_FIND_DATA is a structure
        // Contains information about the file that is found by the FindFirstFile
        WIN32_FIND_DATAW Info;
        // Find first file inside search path
        HANDLE Find = ::FindFirstFileW(search, &Info);

        // If  FindFirstFile(search, &fd); fails return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
        // If Find is not equal to INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE do the loop inside the
        // IF condition

        if (Find != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            do {

                // DWORD dwFileAttributes , FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY ident a directory
                // If condition is fine lets push file mane into string vector
                if (!(Info.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {
                    // Fill vector of names
                    names_ofFiles.push_back(Info.cFileName);

                }

                // do - while there is next file
                //::FindNextFile the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero and the Info contain //information about next file

            } while (::FindNextFile(Find, &Info));
            ::FindClose(Find);
        }

        // Return result
        return names_ofFiles;
    }


    int main(int argc, const char** argv)

    {

        // your path where you can load all images 
        string Path2 = "C:\\Users\\Ksheeraja K S\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\Images";
        // Vector that contain all images file mames
        vector<string> vectorOfFileNameWithinPath = getNamesOfFile(Path2);



        // Load all images and display
        // and store inside the another vector StoredImages

        int pos_count = 0;
        std::vector<Mat> StoredImages;
        for (int i = 0; i < vectorOfFileNameWithinPath.size() - 1; ++i)
            {
                // Path "C://NegativeSample/" + i th "Filename.jpg"

                string cesta = Path2 + vectorOfFileNameWithinPath[i];
                // Read image into Mat container
                Mat img = imread(cesta, IMREAD_COLOR);
                // Store images in vector you can use later for example in own ML training
                StoredImages.push_back(img);
                    // Display single image
                    namedWindow("Display", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
                imshow("Display", img);
                int key1 = waitKey(10);
                // Increase number of positive samples in StoredImages
                // Later we push into same vector negative samples
                // and we need to know, where the boundary is
                pos_count = pos_count + 1;

            }

    }
```

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::wstring> names_ofFiles`.

Comment: The error message does not agree with the code you posted. According to the message you probably have `std::vector<String> names_ofFiles;` (which is also wrong, but not for the same reason).

Comment: `wprintf()` is not the right way to convert a `char` string into a `wchar_t` string. Use `MultiByteToWideChar()` or equivalent instead. And you are trying to push `wchar_t` strings into a `vector` of `char` strings, which doesn't work either (hence the compiler error), you would need to use `WideCharToMultiByte()` or equivalent instead. Otherwise, just use the `A`nsi-based APIs instead (`FindFirstFileA`, etc) and forget all this conversion nonesense.

Comment: you need to review [mre]

Comment: Info.cFileName is of type WCHAR array so you need to convert it into std::wstring and use std::vector<std::wstring> for storing file names